# file marked as key file not getting unistalled while using installshield

Tags: installshield-2012

I am creating msie using installshield2012 professional.I am adding one of my project primary output to msie ,component of which is marked as key file.If i don't mark it as key file my custom installer file in project doesn't get called which is trouble for me but marking it as key file keeps the files uninstalled after uninstalling application.
Is there any way to delete the key files??(permanent and shared properties are set to NO)

Answer (score 4):

InstallShield MSI packages work with Windows to determine which files should get removed and which should be left behind during an install.  If the file is a shared DLL used by other applications, it will be left behind during install.  If the file is still in use (perhaps a service or system tray app), it will be left installed only until the next reboot.  You can always check the Windows Installer log files to determine why a file has been left behind, but here are a few easy things you can try:

First, determine which component the file is the key path of and then switch to the "Components" view in InstallShield 2012 and highlight the component. Review that component's attributes.

1) make sure that Permanant = No.
2) If you are confident this file is not shared with other applications, you can set Shared = No.
3) Reboot after your uninstall test to see if the file gets removed during a reboot.

Comment: I was having an issue where after an upgrade, performing an uninstall would leave some files behind.  The culprit was the Shared setting in my case, changing it from Yes to No allowed the subsequent uninstall to clean them all up.